# ForwardAdd pass gets weird results when a point light is on in Unity

Tags: unity, shaders, alpha-blending

I'm writing a custom shader for the transparent object with built-in pipeline of Unity2022.3.9f1.

For Subshader the Tags set like below

```
Tags { "LightMode"="ForwardBase" "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True"}
```

For base pass everything is ok and the Tags look like below

```
Tags { "LightMode"="ForwardBase"}
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
ZWrite Off
```

And for additive pass, I set them like below

```
Tags { "LightMode"="ForwardAdd"}
Blend SrcAlpha One // Or Blend One One
ZWrite Off
```

Now when a point light is on, the blending is wrong no matter `Blend SrcAlpha One` or `Blend One One`. The result looks like below

[image]

I'm confused what happened and how should I fix this?

PS. I'm using Blinn Phong to illuminate everything and the code is

```
//Lighting
UNITY_LIGHT_ATTENUATION(atten, i, i.positionWS);

float3 worldLightDir = normalize(UnityWorldSpaceLightDir(i.positionWS));
float3 ambient = UNITY_LIGHTMODEL_AMBIENT.xyz;
float3 diffuse = _LightColor0.rgb * _Diffuse.rgb * max(0, dot(normalWS, worldLightDir));
float3 halfDir = normalize(worldLightDir + viewDir);
float3 specular = _LightColor0.rgb * _Specular.rgb * pow(max(0, dot(normalWS, halfDir)), _Gloss);
float3 lighting = ambient + (diffuse + specular) * atten;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The funny thing is that I get rid of `ambient` in the ForwardAdd pass and then it's working as I imagine.

Quite confused...

Comment: Ambient should be applied only once, in the forward base, not repeatedly with every additional light in forward add. Otherwise you end up multiplying the ambient brightness by the number of direct lights incident on the surface.